# JSON data, properties are sometimes arrays sometimes objects

Tags: json

I'm reading a JSON response from a third party and I'm finding that some of the properties return in the notation for a single object when there is only one object to be returned and when there is multiple objects for the property the value is returned as an array of objects.

Example of a single object in the response

```
{
  "data": {
    "property1":"value",
    "property2":"value",
    "property3":"value"
  }
}
```

Example of an array of objects in the response

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "property1":"value",
    "property2":"value",
    "property3":"value"
  },
  {
    "property1":"value",
    "property2":"value",
    "property3":"value"
  },
  {
    "property1":"value",
    "property2":"value",
    "property3":"value"
  },
  {
    "property1":"value",
    "property2":"value",
    "property3":"value"
  }
 ]
}
```

Why would the two different response formats be acceptable from the same endpoint?

Comment: Well, technically it is acceptable. But rather complicated to parse in strongly typed environments. IMHO it is bab prsctice through. It would be the best to return array in both cases.

Comment: I agree, I would return an array in both cases

Answer (score 1):

This question bothered me as well whenever I saw it happening. I never really liked having to check the value in order to know how to access it.

One could argue that doing this saves some space in the payload. You save two bytes omitting the `[]` when there's only a single value. But it's weak IMHO and manipulating the data is harder as we already know.

But looking at it in a different way, this seems to make some sense: it's optimizing for the more common result, a single value. I've seen my fair share of data formats where the structure was very strict. For example, a recursive dictionary-like structure where any property that would contain an object, *must* be an array of that object. So in a deeply nested object, accessing a value may look like this:

```
root.data[0].aparent[0].thechild[0].myvalue
```

vs:

```
root.data.aparent.thechild.myvalue
```

If there were actually multiple values, then using an array would be appropriate.

I don't necessarily buy this since you still have to do a check, you'd have to do *some* tests before consuming the data (like if a response didn't came back). This type of response might make more sense in languages that have some form of pattern matching.